# What warm clothes should I take when traveling in southeast Asia?

Tags: clothing, southeast-asia, mountains, motorcycles, mountain-climbing

While it's mostly very hot in southeast Asia, I plan to do some **hikes** that can go up and above 3000m. Considering some of these hikes will be at night in order to catch the sun rise, it'll be pretty cold I assume.

I also plan to rent a motorbike every now and then, and again, probably ride it at night in some occasions, so I'll probably freeze if I don't have anything warm to put on.

Any tips on what to pack to avoid being cold in those circumstances? Anything compact is welcome.

Comment: Some countries also have very wide temperature range and high humidity, that's different than just altitude cold.

Comment: A light fleece and a windstopper should do.When you hike you move and hence warm yourself up. On a motorbike the windstopper is what saves you from being cold.

Answer (score 4):

For upper body, you’ll need a windproof, breakable jacket and a medium jacket full of down or synthetic fill.

For lower body, you'll need a pair of gore-tex windproof, waterproof and breathable trousers. Some medium weight polar fleece trousers, some medium weight thermal leggings, a pair of walking trousers (not cotton), some nylon shorts (not cotton) quick-drying and finally, some lightweight long-johns.

And don't forget to protect your head and feet as well with a lightweight warm hat and plastic boots.

Safe hiking! :)

Comment: Protect your hat? I think you meant head.

Comment: Sorry. It's my typing mistake. I mean head. Thanks!

Comment: @TristaKim Nice answer, will definitely investigate all this. +1 for the sexy long johns :D